# .net framework versions (or what runs what?)

Tags: .net, frameworks, version

OK, this is rather broad question but ... Is there a chart that says what version of the framework will run what?

So, I guess it brakes down into two questions

1 - Are the frameworks 100% backward compatible? I've had a Framework 2.0 Website run 1.1 dlls, so I assume 2.0 will run 1.1.  Will this work for a windows app?  Will it work for all versions?

2 - Is a framework ever forward compatible?  I know the reverse of above will not work but will it work for any set of versions?

So, how important is it to keep the versions on your clients' machines synced with your build version?

Is there a best pratice in the .net community on how to make your software work for the most number of clients without forcing non-technical users to download newer/different versions of the .net framework?

Comment: I think there are way too many changes between the frameworks for everything to fit into a single chart.  You can google ".NET breaking changes" and find pretty good documentation on what has changed between versions, but it's never in one central location.

Comment: I'm actually really curious about the 2.0 website that ran 1.1 DLLs... did it have no dependencies on other DLLs, including System?  I'm fairly certain that's not possible...

Comment: Way back when - when we updated our site to the 2.0 framework, we did not recompile the vast majority of our dlls.  The only ones we did had breaking changes in them

(Now I kinda fuzzily know that there is a difference between ASP.Net frameworks and the .Net framework versions so I'm not to clear on the differences so this next comment may be technically in error)

When we updated the website to the 3.5 .Net Framework we also did not have to make any changes.

Comment: I just talked to a Co-Worker.  We currently have a page that was built in 1.1 and is inheriting a base object that is in a 3.5 dll.  Could the different framework JIT's be handling the "cross talk"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if .NET version X installs side-by-side with .NET version Y, then .NET version X is not compatible (backwards or forwards) with .NET version Y. This is a rule I've been using for quite some time (since .NET 2.0 came out). It's probably too safe for small-scale applications, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Here are some concrete examples:

- .NET 4.0 will not run .NET 3.x or earlier applications properly
- .NET 3.5 will run .NET 3.0 & .NET 2.0 applications, but not .NET 1.1
- .NET 3.0 will run .NET 2.0 applications, but not .NET 1.1
- .NET 2.0 will not run .NET 1.1
- .NET 4.0 installs side-by-side with .NET 3.5/3.0/2.0 and with .NET 1.1
- .NET 3.5, 3.0, and 2.0 do not install side-by-side with each other
- .NET 3.5/3.0/2.0 installs side-by-side with .NET 1.1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the "major" versions to date are:

- 1.0
- 1.1
- 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 (I believe these were split out due to major C# extensions)
- 4.0

Frameworks on different lines install side-by-side and do not run each other; those on the same line can be used interchangeably so long as the host machine has at least the version of the assembly installed.

All .NET versions currently come with Windows - they are now considered part of the operating system and follow its life cycle.  (See http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?alpha=.NET+Framework&sort=PN) If your users have been keeping their computer up-to-date, you should have no problems using the latest .NET Framework version.

Make sure that, for your configuration files later than 1.0, you include the `<supportedRuntime>` element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx

As Jim Schubert mentions in his comment, your C# code may compile on later versions, but there are some breaking changes.

Comment: There are no C# extensions in 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen a chart anywhere but generally, you don't worry about backwards compatibility. The only important thing is making sure that your clients have the minimum framework installed.

And no, none of the .NET versions are forward compatible.